# Does PhoneGap support Windows Tablet?

Tags: cordova

Does PhoneGap support Windows Tablet?
  I want to create phone gap application for widows 8 tablet. need to know can it be done.

Answer (score 1):

Although the Cordova (PhoneGap) 3.6 documentation lists Windows 8 as being supported, not all the API is supported e.g. whitelist. There doesn't seem to be much activity.

These plugins are not supported: 
*battery*, *console*, *globalization*, *statusbar*

The test cases are misleading in that all the battery tests pass. 
It is not possible to save contacts.
Also *vibration* (ok its a tablet but why do the tests pass?).
Also *splashscreen* https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-7137 this issue was raised in July and has not been commented on. Both tests fail.

JIRA issues raised seem to be languishing.

Microsoft outsourced the work for Windows Phone to Akvelon as described [here](http://www.akvelon.com/mobile-technology/apache-cordova-open-source-mobile-frameworks).

There doesn't seem to be any info on tablet work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it support windows tablets, but same it like there are few limitation and other phonegap features not supported in windows also like local storage and web storage

Answer (score 0):

Windows Surface is not a Windows Phone, is a Windows Tablet, You can develop for Both with same "class Library" , but you want to have two different project. **One for Windows Phone 8** and **one for Windows 8 application**.

You can read [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj714071%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for better explain.

Also, I don't think PhoneGap manage Windows 8.
Unlike Androïd, You don't publish the same project for smartphones and tablet with Windows.

A Windows Phone project is just for Windows phone, a Windows 8 Application is for Tablet, Laptop and Computer using Windows 8 ^^

So you Can not do the same for Windows Phone 8 and Windows Surface. Because the have 2 stores for each so you have to deploy Windows Phone 8 app to the Windows Surface store.

Best luck

Actually there is a [**Cordova project**](https://github.com/apache/cordova-windows) for Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the late response.
phonegap doesn't provide full support on windows store applications but it supports windows phone.
you can use winjs instead of phonegap.windows store html5/javascript application provides all the features supported in phonegap.